# Lucene.NET getting the most recently indexed document

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

My problem is in finding the fastest way to get the last (timestamp-wise) indexed Lucene document.

Here is what the fields in the document look like:

```
        // Index file contents
        Field contentField = new Field(
            FieldContent, 
            message.content,
            Field.Store.YES, 
            Field.Index.ANALYZED, 
            Field.TermVector.YES);

        // The id of the document
        Field messageIdField = new Field(
            FieldMessageId,
            message.serverMessageId,
            Field.Store.YES,
            Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);

        // The dateTime that the document was created
        Field timeStampField = new Field(
            FieldTimeStamp,
            message.creationDate.ToString(),
            Field.Store.YES,
            Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
```

Currently I assume one viable solution is to sort all the documents in the index by the timestampField of the documents and just pick the top one. Is there a search query I could make which would be better fitted for this purpose?

Comment: why one would want to do that?

Comment: Well whenever I index a message, I want to compare the TF-IDF of the message to the previous one. In order to do so, I need the document ID of the previous message inserted into the index. Thus I believe a search is necessary since there are no guarantees of the Lucene document ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

First, ensure that your "timestamp" field is sortable. ToString() is culture sensitive so isn't guaranteed to be orderable. ToString("o") is ok, but...

I would prefer to use a Numeric field and put DateTime.UtcNow().Ticks in it. (use .SetLongValue(ticks) )

Then,

- create a Sort for that field ordered descending. Something like

  ```
  var sort = new Sort(new SortField(TimestampFieldName, SortField.LONG, true))
  ```
- Use the Searcher for that takes a collector (note the "1" in the .Create line = only return a max of one result)

  ```
  var collector = TopFieldCollector.Create(sort, 1, false, trackScores, trackScores, trackScores);
  searcher.Search(query, filter, collector);
  var topdocs = collector.TopDocs();
  ```
- Get the Document

  ```
  var topdoc = topDocs.ScoreDocs[0];
  var doc = container.Document(topdoc.Doc);
  ```
- profit!!!